# Is it hard to evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{3} \ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} d x$?

Tags: integration, substitution

When I encountered this question, I just wondered whether there is a simple way to tackle the integral. After trying many substitutions, I still failed. Suddenly, integration by parts come to my mind and helped me solve the problem.  I first integrate the part $$\dfrac{x^{3}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$$ and then evaluate it via integration by parts.

Are there any alternate methods other than integration by parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) \, dx \\
&= -2 \int_0^1 \frac{\frac{(1-y)^3}{(1+y)^3}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1+y)^2}}} \ln(y) \frac{dy}{(1+y)^2} \tag1 \\
&= - \int_0^1 \frac{(1-y)^3}{\sqrt y (1+y)^4} \ln(y) \, dy \\
&= - \int_0^1 \frac{(1-z^2)^3}{z(1+z^2)^4} \ln(z^2) \cdot 2z\,dz \tag2 \\
&= -4 \int_0^1 \frac{(1-z^2)^3}{(1+z^2)^4} \ln(z) \, dz \\
&= 4 \int_0^1 \frac{(1-z^2)^3}{(1+z^2)^4} \left[\int_z^1 \frac{dw}w\right] \, dz & \tag3 \\
&= 4 \int_0^1 \frac1w \left[\int_0^w \left(\frac8{(1+z^2)^4} - \frac{12}{(1+z^2)^3} + \frac6{(1+z^2)^2} - \frac1{1+z^2}\right) \, dz\right] \, dw \tag4 \\
&= 4 \int_0^1 \frac{3w^4+2w^2+3}{(w^2+1)^3} \, dw \\
&= \frac43 \int_0^1 \left(\frac4{(w^2+1)^3} - \frac4{(w^2+1)^2} + \frac3{w^2+1}\right) \, dw \tag5 \\
&= \frac43 \times \frac{5\pi}{24} = \boxed{\frac{5\pi}6}
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ : substitute $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$
- $(2)$ : substitute $z=\sqrt y$
- $(3)$ : integral definition of $\ln(z)$
- $(4)$ : change integration order; expand into partial fractions; integrate subsequent terms by parts
- $(5)$ : partial fractions again

Comment: What a powerful substitution!

Answer (score 4):

$ \text{We are going to evaluate the integral}$
$\displaystyle I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{3} \ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} d x. \tag*{}$
$\textrm{using integration by parts only.}$

$\textrm{Noting that}$
$\displaystyle \quad \frac{d}{d x} \ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\frac{2}{1-x^{2}},\tag*{}$
$\textrm{we prefer to using integration by parts.}$
$\begin{align*} \displaystyle I&= \quad \int \frac{x^{3}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} d x \\&=\displaystyle \int \frac{x-x\left(1-x^{2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} d x \\&=\displaystyle \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} d x-\int x \sqrt{1-x^{2}} d x \\&=\displaystyle -\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+\frac{\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}+c \\\displaystyle &=-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{3}\left(2+x^{2}\right)+c\end{align*} \tag*{} $
$\textrm{We can now start the evaluation.}$
$ \displaystyle \begin{aligned}I\displaystyle =&\int_{0}^{1} \ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) d\left(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{3}\left(2+x^{2}\right)\right) \\\displaystyle =&-\left[\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{3}\left(2+x^{2}\right)\ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\right]_{0}^{1}+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{3}\left(2+x^{2}\right)\left(\frac{2}{1-x^{2}}\right) d x \\  \displaystyle =&\frac{2}{3} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2+x^{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} d x\end{aligned} \tag*{}$

$\text {As usual, we let } x=\sin \theta ,$
$\displaystyle \begin{aligned} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2+x^{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} d x=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2+\sin ^{2} \theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin ^{2} \theta}} \cdot \cos \theta d \theta \\&=[2 \theta]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1-\cos 2 \theta}{2} d \theta \\&=\pi+\frac{1}{2}\left[\theta-\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \\&=\frac{5 \pi}{4}\end{aligned} \tag*{} $

We can now conclude that
$\displaystyle \boxed{\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{3} \ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} d x =\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{5 \pi}{4}=\frac{5 \pi}{6}}\tag*{} $

Answer (score 1):

Afterwards, I found that the substitution of trigonometric function works as well as integration by parts!

Letting $x=\cos 2 \theta$ yields$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{0} \frac{\cos ^{3} 2 \theta \ln \left(\frac{2 \cos ^{3} \theta}{2 \sin ^{2} \theta}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\cos ^{3} 2 \theta}}(-2 \sin 2 \theta) d \theta \\
&=-4 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \cos ^{3} 2 \theta \ln (\tan \theta) d \theta
\end{aligned}
$$

Noting that $$
\begin{aligned}
\int \cos ^{3} 2 \theta d \theta &=\frac{1}{2} \int\left(1-\sin ^{2} 2 \theta\right) d(\sin 2 \theta) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin 2 \theta-\frac{\sin ^{3} 2 \theta}{3}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

We can now use integration by parts again. $$
\begin{aligned}
I=&-4\left(\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin 2 \theta-\frac{\sin ^{2} 2 \theta}{3}\right) \ln (\tan \theta)\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin 2 \theta-\frac{\sin ^{3} 2 \theta}{3}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{\tan \theta}  \cdot \sec ^{2} \theta d\theta \right)\\
=& 4 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(1-\frac{\sin ^{2} 2 \theta}{3}\right) d \theta \\
=& 4\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-\frac{4}{3} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1-\cos 4 \theta}{2} d \theta  \\
=& \frac{5 \pi}{6}
\end{aligned}
$$